# How to Enable Azure AD B2C Login in React APP

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented azure AD B2C login in my React APP using react-aad-msal(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal) package but the application is login through Microsoft Login Page.. I want to login directly from my React APP login page.

Comment: As you are using Azure AD B2C the login request flows through the Microsoft login page. Are you looking to avoid login popup and looking for login redirect...?  for more undertanding Can we know the main purpose of using Azure AD B2C in your application

Comment: Actually, we want users can directly login from our website.. we do not want any login page or popup. We have already a login page user enters his credentials and we can get the access token after submitting.

Comment: That means you dont want to use Azure AD B2C Authentication.? Whats the purpose of using Azure AD B2C in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C only supports redirecting the user to the AAD B2C login page (Web Apps, JS apps), or using a Pop Up modal in a Javascript app. API based auth (ROPC flow) is only supported in Mobile Apps. You cannot embed our B2C login page into you applications page.